# What is the process whereby ~/bin gets on my path in git bash?

Tags: git-bash

I noticed that in `git bash` I can put executable files in my `~/bin` directory and the system will find them.  However, that directory is not on my Windows path and I am not doing anything in my `.profile` that modifies my path, and I don't have any `.bashrc` file.

I don't really have a problem with this, but I would like to understand how it's happening.

Comment: gotta love the stackoverflow "please change your question wording"... i haven't used "whereby" in a while

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> that directory is not on my Windows path

It is on your bash PATH environment variable.

And it is there because of the `/etc/profile.d/env.sh` script (`C:\path\to\git\etc\profile.d`)

```
vonc@voncm MINGW64 /etc/profile.d
$ cat env.sh
# Add bin path in the home directory ontop of the PATH variable
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

`HOME` is by default your `%USERPROFILE%`